# Calling another script and retrieving multiple values from that script in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I would like to run several python scripts in parallel, called from a main python script. As each of these sub-scripts complete, I would like to retrieve multiple values from that sub-script in the main script.

In the example below I start main.py, which then calls sub.py 10 times. I then want to wait until all 10 instances of sub.py are done and retrieve the lists from each instance. This does work with a single numeric value, but I would like to retrieve a list of strings, or even one single large string.

So, two questions...

1. Am I doing the parallel processing thing correctly? Just because it works doesn't make it "correct".
2. Is it possible to pass a list or large string from sub.py back to main.py, or am I stuck with single numeric values ala exit codes?

main.py

```
#
# main.py - main program module
#

import subprocess
import time

procs=[]

# Open 10 python processes
for i in range(10):
    procs.append(subprocess.Popen(["python","./sub.py"]))

# Loop until no "None" returned
while True:
    for proc in procs:
        if proc.poll() == None:
            break
    else:
        break

for proc in procs:
    print("{} values".format(proc.poll()))
```

sub.py

```
#
# sub.py - Called by main.py
# 
# Generate a random list of numbers, then sleep a couple seconds
#

import time
import random
import sys

out = [] # List containing our random values
amt = random.randint(1,10)  # How many values to return
slp = random.randint(1,4)   # Number of seconds to sleep

# Generate random values in a list
for i in range(amt):
    out.append(random.randint(1,10))

print("Sleeping {} seconds.".format(slp))
time.sleep(slp)

sys.exit(out)
```

Comment: The usual way to get output from sub-processes would to for the programs to write to stdout/stderr, i.e.: `sys.stdout.write()`, and then read these pipes from the parent program.  But it's equally valid to write to files and then read these in.